# New oven on general plug circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, oven

We had an ageing gas oven replaced with a new electric oven, which we had installed by Currys (A UK electrical retailer who also do installations). I noticed at the weekend that it has been installed on the same circuit as the general downstairs wall plugs and not on the existing oven specific circuit (the gas oven had an electric grill).

So now the only thing on the oven circuit is a single plug socket which is incorporated in the now ineffective oven power on-off switch on the kitchen wall.

Is this normal and/or safe? The oven looks like it only needed a 13 amp circuit, and I assume that the original oven circuit was higher than that. But it seems to me that it would still be best to isolate the oven from the general plug socket circuit, if only to ensure a safe load is never exceeded.

Here is a link to the oven: http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/appliances/ovens/realistisk-oven-grey-green-art-80300924/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is this normal**

No, it is normal to have an electric oven on a separate radial circuit with its own MCB in the consumer unit. For example a dedicated 32A "Cooker" circuit.

Ovens are normally hardwired through a dual-pole isolating switch adjacent to the oven.

> **and/or safe?**

It is safe so long as the installer calculated the loading on the downstairs ring circuit. There are formula to be used which take into account the type of appliances, the number of sockets and the conductor sizes. (see Diversity and Demand below for load calculations with examples)

The [REALISTISK Oven](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/doc/advice_and_instructions/realistisk__aa-1513580-1.pdf) has a *total* rating of 2.7 kW, which is only slightly more than a typical electric kettle. It is also less than 13A on a 230V circuit, so won't be a problem for the actual socket, 13A fused plug and cable. However you obviously can't have all four heating elements on, from cold, at the same time (top, bottom, fan & grill).

> **it seems to me that it would still be best to isolate the oven from the general plug socket circuit**

I believe that would be normal practise.

---

Useful links

- [*Radial circuits for socket outlets, cookers, shower and many other items*, John Ward.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=At7AnMV7Xd0) (11:00)
- [*Maximum Diversity and Demand*, John Ward.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq0uODypaGI&t=311s) (16:10)

Comment: OK, thanks for the comprehensive answer. I think I'll speak to Curry's and see what they say about putting it back on its own circuit.